# How to get an events of device lock/unlock button in ios device without using non-public APIs?

Tags: ios, events, darwin, springboard

I had already used non-public APIs such as Darvin's Notification and "com.apple.springboard.lockstate" of  library for receiving device lock/unlock state. But Apple has rejected this app because it's using above non-public APIs.

Is there any other events to check for device lock/unlock in ios device?

Comment: Do you mean the sleep/wake button (side button), since if the power is off you can't run any code :). I don't believe that there are any public APIs for this.  Perhaps you could explain a little more about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes. I mean the device lock/unlock button of ios device.

Comment: If you are trying to react to the device entering the lock state, then there may be some solutions for detecting that.  Trying to perform some action based on the sleep/wake button itself may fall afoul of the app store review guidelines, since they forbid re-purposing device controls